# How to pivot non-numeric columns in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, greatest-n-per-group

I have data that looks like this:

| ID | FIELD_NAME | FIELD_VALUE | UPDATE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | Elmer Fudd | 2023-01-01 |
| 1 | Age | 30 | 2023-02-01 |
| 1 | Age | 29 | 2023-03-01 |
| 2 | Name | Bugs Bunny | 2023-03-01 |
| 2 | Name | Bugz Bunny | 2023-04-01 |
| 2 | Age | 13 | 2023-04-01 |

I want to pivot only the most recent rows for each ID and FIELD_NAME and pivot them so the final table looks like this:

| ID | NAME | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Elmer Fudd | 29 |
| 2 | Bugz Bunny | 13 |

How would you suggest I do this using Snowflake SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Snowflake, I would recommend a conditional [`max_by()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/min_by):

```
select id,
    max_by(case when field_name = 'Name' then field_value end, update_date) name,
    max_by(case when field_name = 'Age'  then field_value end, update_date) age
from mytable t
group by id
```